# jquery name$= or name=

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets say I have named some elements with the following structure:

- 1:0
- 11:0
- 21:0

When I was looking for the value of 1:0 I found that the following code returned everything with a 1:0 in it:

```
alert($("[name$=" + arrayVal[i] + "]").val());
```

However when I took the "$" out it appears to only return the 1:0 in my above example.  I did a quick search on Google but couldn't find anything to support this finding.  Does anyone have any links they could point me to for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, `$=` means 'ends with', and `=` means 'is equal to'.

[Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: That's awesome.  Do you have any links to support that?  I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

The `$=` is the [attribute ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), so what you got was the expected behavior.

For a full read, whch seems to be what you're after, [you can find all of the attribute selectors here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

When in doubt, go to the source, the [jQuery API Site](http://api.jquery.com/), a quick search will answer *most* of your "what's this operator?" questions :)

Comment: Thanks.  I have made that site a favorite.

Answer (score 1):

`$=` is the "attribute ends with" selector.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/